# How can I add a character between the wheels in a uipickerview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xamarin

For instance, I want to add a , between the digits of the 3rd and 4th wheel.

I cannot find any examples or references of it. Xamarin example would be best, but Objective-C is fine as well. Or any links ofcourse!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this by adding a label and set it so its always centered vertically between the pickers. That works like a charm.

Comment: Trying that out. Thanks.

Comment: It did. I hoped there was another way. Thanks